# Core Audio - Interapp Audio - How to Retrieve output audio packets from Node app inside Host App?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, audio, core-audio

I am writing an `HOST` app that uses Core Audio's new iOS 7 Inter App Audio technology to pull audio from a single `NODE` "generator" app and route it into my `host` app. I am using the Audio Components Services and Audio Unit Component Services C frameworks to achieve this.

What I want to achieve is to establish a connection to an external node app who can generate sound. I want that sound to be routed into my host app and for my host app to be able to directly access the audio packet data as a stream of raw audio data.

I have written the code inside my `HOST` app that does the following sequentially:

1. Sets up and activates an audio session with the correct session category.
2. Refreshes a list of interapp audio compatible apps who are of type`kAudioUnitType_RemoteGenerator` or `kAudioUnitType_RemoteInstrument` (I'm not interested in effects apps).
3. Pulls out the last object from that list and attempts to establish a connection using `AudioComponentInstanceNew()`
4. Sets the Audio Stream Basic Description that my host app needs the audio format in.
5. Sets up audio unit properties and callbacks as well as an audio unit render callback on the output scope (bus).
6. Initializes the audio unit.

So far so good, I have been able to successfully establish a connection, but my problem is that my render callback is not being called at all. What I am having trouble understanding is how exactly to pull the audio from the node application? I have read that I need to call `AudioUnitRender()` in order to initiate a rendering cycle on the node app, but how exactly does this need to be setup in my situation? I have seen other examples where AudioUnitRender() is called from inside the rendering callback, but this isnt going to work for me because my render callback isn't being called currently. Do I need to setup up my own audio processing thread and periodically call `AudioUnitRender()` on my 'node'?

The following is the code described above inside my `HOST` app.

```
static OSStatus MyAURenderCallback (void                        *inRefCon,
                                    AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
                                    const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
                                    UInt32                      inBusNumber,
                                    UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
                                    AudioBufferList             *ioData) 
{
     //Do something here with the audio data? 
     //This method is never being called? 
     //Do I need to puts AudioUnitRender() in here? 
}

    - (void)start
    {
        [self configureAudioSession];
        [self refreshAUList];
    }

    - (void)configureAudioSession
    {
        NSError *audioSessionError = nil;
        AVAudioSession *mySession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [mySession setPreferredSampleRate: _graphSampleRate error: &audioSessionError];
        [mySession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &audioSessionError];
        [mySession setActive: YES error: &audioSessionError];
        self.graphSampleRate = [mySession sampleRate];
    }

    - (void)refreshAUList
    {
        _audioUnits = @[].mutableCopy;

        AudioComponentDescription searchDesc = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, foundDesc;
        AudioComponent comp = NULL;

        while (true) {

        comp = AudioComponentFindNext(comp, &searchDesc);

        if (comp == NULL) break;

        if (AudioComponentGetDescription(comp, &foundDesc) != noErr) continue;

        if (foundDesc.componentType == kAudioUnitType_RemoteGenerator || foundDesc.componentType == kAudioUnitType_RemoteInstrument) {

            RemoteAU *rau = [[RemoteAU alloc] init];
            rau->_desc = foundDesc;
            rau->_comp = comp;

            AudioComponentCopyName(comp, &rau->_name);
            rau->_image = AudioComponentGetIcon(comp, 48);
            rau->_lastActiveTime = AudioComponentGetLastActiveTime(comp);

            [_audioUnits addObject:rau];
        }
    }

    [self connect];
}

- (void)connect  {

    if ([_audioUnits count] <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    RemoteAU *rau = [_audioUnits lastObject];

    AudioUnit myAudioUnit;

    //Node application will get launched in background
    Check(AudioComponentInstanceNew(rau->_comp, &myAudioUnit));

    AudioStreamBasicDescription format = {0};
    format.mChannelsPerFrame  = 2;
    format.mSampleRate = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] sampleRate];
    format.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
    UInt32 propSize = sizeof(format);
    Check(AudioFormatGetProperty(kAudioFormatProperty_FormatInfo, 0, NULL, &propSize, &format));

    //Output format from node to host
    Check(AudioUnitSetProperty(myAudioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &format, sizeof(format)));

    //Setup a render callback to the output scope of the audio unit representing the node app
    AURenderCallbackStruct callbackStruct = {0};
    callbackStruct.inputProc = MyAURenderCallback;
    callbackStruct.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
    Check(AudioUnitSetProperty(myAudioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, kAudioUnitScope_Output, 0, &callbackStruct, sizeof(callbackStruct)));

    //setup call backs
    Check(AudioUnitAddPropertyListener(myAudioUnit, kAudioUnitProperty_IsInterAppConnected, IsInterappConnected, NULL));
    Check(AudioUnitAddPropertyListener(myAudioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_HostTransportState, AudioUnitPropertyChangeDispatcher, NULL));

    //intialize the audio unit representing the node application
    Check(AudioUnitInitialize(myAudioUnit));
}
```

Comment: where is documentation to inter app audio located on web ? i am not able to google it ...

Comment: @Sabobin did you ever manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: Hey did u got anywhere with this?